# .remove() in jquery doesn't remove DOM instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to remove a DOM element "div",

```
$('#emDiv').on("click", ':button[data-emp-del="true"]', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        // Get Row - "emp0" or "emp1" etc ...
        var rowId = "#" + $(this).data('emp-id');

        // Remove the DIV
        $(rowId).fadeOut('normal', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        // The results below returns even the one that was removed
        // $('div[id^="emp"]')

        return false;
    });
```

How to completely remove the DIV above instantly as I want to loop over remaining DIVs change their IDs.

Thanks

Comment: What did you expect? You remove the element after the fade out animation has completed. That doesn't happen instantly.

Comment: @bhaidar Esailija's comment code would work... Please try it.

Comment: $(this).remove() removes that div, but after the fadeout is done, I want to loop over remaining divs - check commented line below

Comment: @bhaidar - So do that in the callback, after the call to `remove`.

Comment: why is this question tagged in asp.net-mvc-3

Comment: Even with $(rowId).remove() still $('div[id^="emp"]') returns all divs even the one that was removed.

Comment: This is part of MVC 3 application, that's why I tagged it, in case someone else had a dynamic add/remove DIV in MVC 3, he/she could look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the remaning code also in the fadeout callback function. The javascript statements executed asynchronosly thats why you get the element. Instead your element get deleted after 1 second.

Comment: This is your answer. You execute the commented line before deleting the element from DOM due to the async nature of jQuery animations.